# SourceSafe plugin keeps checking out my project files

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-sourcesafe-plugin

I have a solution with multiple projects which I don't always want to build at the same time.

So I created several solution configurations like in the following example:

> **Configuration 1**
>
> - Project A is build
> - Project B is build
> - Project C is not build
>
> **Configuration 2**
>
> - Project A is build
> - Project B is not build
> - Project C is build
>
> **etc.**

It was all working very well until yesterday, when I created a couple of new solution configurations. Since this moment, every time I change configuration, all my project files are checked out although they show no difference with their server version.

Could someone explain this behaviour?

And, more importantly, what can I do to stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be hard, but: Stop using SourceSafe, it's well [past its support deadline](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?alpha=Visual%20SourceSafe) and there is a much better alternative in either [visual-studio-online](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-online) and [tfs2013](/questions/tagged/tfs2013) (Express if you need free) both supporting [tfvc](/questions/tagged/tfvc) and [git](/questions/tagged/git).

Or any of the non-Microsoft options like [github](/questions/tagged/github) and [atlassian-stash](/questions/tagged/atlassian-stash) in the cloud or plain [git](/questions/tagged/git) or [subversion](/questions/tagged/subversion) on premise.

The reason why your projects are checked out may simply be because Visual Studio removes the read-only bit, which is something more modern systems no longer need to rely on as they'll actually compare the file contents to determine whether a file needs to be checked out. I've stopped debugging SourceSafe a long, long time ago.

Comment: SourceSafe is such a pain in the neck... I'd really like stop using it. But it's a little bit out of my hands...

Comment: There is now a VSS to TFS conversion tool from Microsoft. The move is easier than ever before.

Comment: I'm more than tempted. I need to talk to my colleagues. ;o)

Comment: I accepted your answer although it was not really what I expected when I came here. But I guess you're right and changing for another source control solution would be for the greater good.